running an update query in Onprem oracle table from aws glue python shell job
I have a use case that has to update a record in onprem database using python shell job .
The onprem database connection is working and being used in pyspark jobs to read data.
It has a pem file certificate and ssl security is enabled.
Now my issue is how do i pass the certificate information in connection string while working in aws glue job .
error : : DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=sdsfsfdfsdffdsfd+KYod/bJg==).
code :
import sys
import boto3
import oracledb
import ast
    # Oracle connection details using Easy Connect string

session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager')   

    
def get_secret(secret_name):
    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
        return get_secret_value_response
    except Exception as e:
        raise 


def update_table(table_name):
    try :
        print("im here update table")
        cred=get_secret("inbound-db/OraDim")
        cred=ast.literal_eval(cred["SecretString"])
        print(f"credentials {cred}")
        user =cred["username"]
        password =cred["password"]
        '''
        conn_str = 'jdbc:oracle:thin://@host:port/service_name'
        
        conn_str=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
         (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=True)))'
         
        conn_str=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
         (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=True)))'
         
         conn_str=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
         (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid_name))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=True)))'
         
            conn_str=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
         (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid_name))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=True)))'
         
        conn_str='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
         (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid_name)))'
          conn_str = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service_name'
          
          connection = oracledb.connect(user="hr", password=userpwd,
                              host="dbhost.example.com", port=1521, sid="orcl")
         conn_str = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:service_name'
         '''
        
        
        
        #print (conn_str)
        #conn = oracledb.connect(user=user, password=password,dsn=conn_str)
        conn = oracledb.connect(user=user, password=password,host=host ,port=port, sid=sid)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print ("update started")
        cursor.execute("UPDATE mytable SET load_completion_flag ='N' WHERE table_name ='xyz'")
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Update successful')
        }
    except Exception as e:
        raise 


I have tried multiple below connection strings
conn_str = 'jdbc:oracle:thin://@host:port/service_name'
    conn_str=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
     (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=True)))'
     
    conn_str=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
     (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=True)))'
     
     conn_str=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
     (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid_name))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=True)))'
     
        conn_str=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
     (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid_name))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=True)))'
     
    conn_str='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host) \
     (PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid_name)))'
      conn_str = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service_name'
      
      connection = oracledb.connect(user="hr", password=userpwd,
                          host="dbhost.example.com", port=1521, sid="orcl")
     conn_str = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:service_name'

